# Conditionally setting one variable's value based on another

Tags: less, less-mixins

I've got a Less variable called `@side`. What I want is to set the variable `@sideOpposite` depending on the value of the `@side` variable. It can take only two values: "left" or "right".

In other words I need a Less equivalent of the JS code:

```
var side = "left",
    sideOpposite = (side === "left")? "right" : "left";
```

I've tried to accomplish this using `when` function, but from what I understand it doesn't work that way and is only applicable to CSS properties, not variables:

```
when (@side = right){
  @sideOpposite: left;
}
when (@side = left){
  @sideOpposite: right;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [Mixin Guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-mixin-guards-feature) and [Ruleset Guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature) (aka "CSS Guards") for `when` usage examples. Since you need to define a variable you'll have to use mixin-based condition (rulesets do not expose their variables to an outer scope). E.g.:

```
.-();
.-() when (@side = right) {
    @sideOpposite: left;
}
.-() when (@side = left) {
    @sideOpposite: right;
}
```

(Use any suitable mixin name instead of `.-`, e.g. `.define-opposite-side`).

---

And with [Argument Pattern Matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching) it can be further simplified just to:

```
.-(@side); 
.-(left)  {@sideOpposite: right}
.-(right) {@sideOpposite: left}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've understand what you want to do, but from what I get about your question, you can do this with a mixin. See example

```
//This is the mixin with default value
.side(@leftORoposite: left) { float: @leftORoposite ;}
```

Invoke this mixin when you need it left with `.side(left)` or when you need right with `.side(right)`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to match with the OP's requirement mate. OP wants something like a ternary operator's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of [the mixin guard feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature) to allow conditional mixins

```
.mixin (@side; @sideOpposite) when (@side = right) { @sideOpposite: left }
.mixin (@side; @sideOpposite) when (@side = left) { @sideOpposite: right }
```