# Making this LESS Mixin more efficient and less redundant?

Tags: less, mixins, redundancy, less-mixins, coding-efficiency

so for a website project I had to create a LESS Mixin which I had never done before. I have the feeling that it is not as efficient as it could be and may be a little redundant. I looked through it but couldnt think of a better way to do it. Maybe you can give me some advice? Dont get me wrong, its working perfectly fine but as mentioned I guess I could do it a little easier when it comes to the LESS code.

So here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/T2Xe9/747/

Example HTML:

```
<style media="screen">
  div {
    background: crimson;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
</style>
<div class="example-1"></div>
<div class="example-2"></div>
<div class="example-3"></div>
<div class="example-4"></div>
```

Mixin with examples:

```
.clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; @width; @direction; @position; @side) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: @width;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";

  & when (@direction = 'up') {
    background: linear-gradient(to top left, @colorOne 0%, @colorOne 50%, @colorTwo 50%, @colorTwo 100%);
  }

  & when (@direction = 'down') {
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, @colorOne 0%, @colorOne 50%, @colorTwo 50%, @colorTwo 100%);
  }

  & when (@position = top) {
    top: 0;
  }

  & when (@position = bottom) {
    bottom: 0;
  }

  & when (@side = 'left') {
    left: 0;
  }

  & when (@side = 'right') {
    right: 0;
  }
}

.clipping-single(@colorOne; @colorTwo; @direction; @position) {
  &:before {
    .clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; 100%; @direction; @position; 'left');
  }
}

.clipping-double(@colorOne; @colorTwo; @direction; @position) {
  & when (@direction = 'up') {
    &:before {
      .clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; 50%; 'up'; @position; 'left');
    }
    &:after {
      .clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; 50%; 'down'; @position; 'right');
    }
  }

  & when (@direction = 'down') {
    &:before {
      .clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; 50%; 'down'; @position; 'left');
    }
    &:after {
      .clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; 50%; 'up'; @position; 'right');
    }
  }
}

.example-1 {
  .clipping-double(crimson, #fff, 'up', top);
}

.example-2 {
  .clipping-double(#fff, crimson, 'down', bottom);
}

.example-3 {
  .clipping-single(#fff, crimson, 'down', bottom);
}

.example-4 {
  .clipping-single(crimson, #fff, 'up', top);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions for you. Both will reduce the redundancy and produce the same CSS as the original version. If *more efficient* means less lines of SASS code then this is also the case.

```
& when (@position = top) {
  top: 0;
}

& when (@position = bottom) {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

can be replace with

```
@{position}: 0;
```

and the same for `@{side}: 0;` but you would have to pass `left` instead of `'left'` as an argument.

The second suggestion is to refactor the line where you set the linear-gradient. The only *variable* is the direction so I would make this a SASS variable to avoid the redundancy of the other linear-gradient parameters.

```
& when (@direction = 'up') {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, @colorOne 0%, @colorOne 50%, @colorTwo 50%, @colorTwo 100%);
}

& when (@direction = 'down') {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, @colorOne 0%, @colorOne 50%, @colorTwo 50%, @colorTwo 100%);
}
```

becomes

```
.define-gradient-direction(@direction);
.define-gradient-direction('up') { @gradientDir: to top left; }
.define-gradient-direction('down') { @gradientDir: to top right; }
background: linear-gradient(@gradientDir, @colorOne 0%, @colorOne 50%, @colorTwo 50%, @colorTwo 100%);
```

**Full code**

```css
.clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; @width; @direction; @position; @side) {
  .define-gradient-direction(@direction);
  .define-gradient-direction('up') { @gradientDir: to top left; }
  .define-gradient-direction('down') { @gradientDir: to top right; }
  
  display: inline-block;
  width: @width;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  background: linear-gradient(@gradientDir, @colorOne 0%, @colorOne 50%, @colorTwo 50%, @colorTwo 100%);
  
  @{position}: 0;
  @{side}: 0;
}

.clipping-single(@colorOne; @colorTwo; @direction; @position) {
  &:before {
    .clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; 100%; @direction; @position; left);
  }
}

.clipping-double(@colorOne; @colorTwo; @direction; @position) {
  & when (@direction = 'up') {
    &:before {
      .clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; 50%; 'up'; @position; left);
    }
    &:after {
      .clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; 50%; 'down'; @position; right);
    }
  }

  & when (@direction = 'down') {
    &:before {
      .clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; 50%; 'down'; @position; left);
    }
    &:after {
      .clipping(@colorOne; @colorTwo; 50%; 'up'; @position; right);
    }
  }
}

.example-1 {
  .clipping-double(crimson, #fff, 'up', top);
}

.example-2 {
  .clipping-double(#fff, crimson, 'down', bottom);
}

.example-3 {
  .clipping-single(#fff, crimson, 'down', bottom);
}

.example-4 {
  .clipping-single(crimson, #fff, 'up', top);
}
```

Edit: thanks to seven-phases-max for pointing out an improvement in the comments. It's now part of the snippet.

Comment: For the `.calc-gradient-direction` thing see a bit more clean method at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25291697/2712740.

Comment: Tahank you, helped very much!